# change chat module css for moodle

Tags: css, moodle

I just recently started a job at a place that is using moodle. they have a theme they've already implemented. However, there is a slight grey border around the message divs in the chat room under the bubble theme. I can open it in chrome and can turn off some css that pertains to td, th and they go away, but I can't seem to figure out where to overwrite the css in my file structure. I've overwritten some css on other parts of the site successfully, but the chat mod doesn't seem to be loading in some of my css. I'm using Moodle 2.3 . On LAMP if that matters. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem but with the formal white theme. The solution was to edit the file "\theme\formal_white\layout\embedded.php".